# Vb.Net: How to execute SQL query inisde datagrid?

Tags: vb.net

I have load a csv file using the code below

```
Dim fi
Dim conn
Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    fi = New FileInfo("C:\path\Book1.csv")
    conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Text;Data Source=" & fi.DirectoryName)
    conn.Open()
    adapter1.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " & fi.Name, conn)
    adapter1.Fill(ds, "DATA")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
End Sub
```

Now, I want to execute a SQL query like create, select, update, etc inside the gridview. For example, I want to create a new column "test" and fill that column with the values from column "a" and "b". But I get error. Can you please correct the code?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        DataGridView2.Columns.Add("test", "test")
        adapter1.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("Update Datagridview1 SET test = a + b", conn)
        Dim dsA As New DataSet
        adapter1.Fill(dsA, "DATA")
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dsA.Tables(0).DefaultView
    Catch exp As Exception
        MsgBox("Error : " & exp.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Error message: he Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Datagridview1.txt'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

Comment: Do you want to create a new column on the database table or just on the datagridview?

Comment: @Steve, only in the datagridview :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this code now, but usually you change the schema of the DataTable linked to the DataGridView to reflect the new column, and, in your specific case set the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) property of the newly created column

```
Dim dv As DataView = CType(DataGridView2.DataSource, DataView)
Dim dc = dv.Table.Columns.Add("test", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
dc.Expression = "[A] + [B]"
```

This strongly depends on the datatype of the columns A and B. Here I suppose that they are both strings